# AppleScript to play a song with a specific artist in iTunes?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to run an Applescript that will play a song in iTunes. The problem is I need the song to have a specific artist as well. Whenever I write some script that uses "artist" I get an error stating that artist could not be accessed.

```
tell application "iTunes"
activate
play track "My Song"
end tell
```

this code works to play a track but I also need to specify the artist so that a track with the same name isn't accidentally played. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust as necessary.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set mySongs to every track of library playlist 1 whose artist is "Styx" and name is "boat on the river"
    repeat with aSong in mySongs
        play aSong
    end repeat
end tell
```